# gradient, with respect to weights, of the cross entropy loss function

Tags: gradient, softmax, cross-entropy

I am trying to train a softmax classifier using gradient descent. To do so, I need to be able to calculate the gradient of the loss function,

$$ L_i = -\log \left( \frac{e^{f_{y_i}}}{\sum_j e^{f_j}} \right) $$

where $ i^{th} $ training example has a score for the $ j^{th} $ class,  $ f_j = X_i \cdot W_j $

I have read through [eli's post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-softmax-function-and-its-derivative/) on the subject but I am still unclear on how to compute the gradient analytically. Can someone show how this is done step by step or point me to a textbook which does?